# Redbean and Yii conflict?

Tags: php, yii, redbean

So here is the important bits of the code inside a normal Yii controller.

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
    require_once('redbean/rb.php');

$config = Yii::app()->getComponents(false);

R::setup($config['db']['connectionString'],
$config['db']['username'],
$config['db']['password'])

$guest = R::dispense( 'guest' );
$guest->email = $row['Guest Email'];
```

The error happens at the dispense() line.

> include(Model_Guestx.php) function.include: failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory (**path
>   redacted**\framework\YiiBase.php:418)
>
> #0 **path
>   redacted**\framework\YiiBase.php(418): CWebApplication->handleError()

The question is WHY is Yii trying to load a Model with the same name as redbean is looking to dispense?

Thanks!

Ken

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what triggers the Yii autoloader but you can include the following code to make Yii skip any models that are created by Redbean:

```
public static function autoload($className)
    {
    if(!strncmp("Model_", $className, strlen("Model_")))
        return true;
    //...rest of yii code...
```

If you add that to the beginning of the YiiBase.php code it will ignore Models beginning with "Model_", which is what Redbean uses. I know it's a hack but unless you create models you intend to use with Yii that fall into that naming category it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This works for models created by Redbean, but might cause problems if you add models to Redbean, because they start with Model_ too.

Comment: Wouldn't it mean that the RedBean models also get ignored by Yii? Why would this hack have any impact on how RedBean loads its models?

Comment: It doesn't. I should be more specific: in my case I use a model added to Redbean apart from Redbean to. So then it should be loaded by the auto loader, but in this case it won't. But I admit this might be a bit exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

Yii has its own class autoloader, and somehow (probably when checking if the model exists) Redbean creates a string that looks like a PHP file. So Yii tries to include it.

You could disable the yii autoloader before you work with Redbean; then reenable it after you finished:

```
    // Turn off our amazing library autoload 
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));   

    Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
    require_once('rb.php');

    R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'password');

    $guest = R::dispense('guest');
    $guest->email = $row['Guest Email'];

    // Once we have finished using the library, give back the 
    // power to Yii... 
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));


    $this->render('index');
```

Credit goes to:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it more universal, why not use the events beforeControllerAction() and afterControllerAction() to disable and enable the Yii autoload in a base controller dedicated to redbena, or if you want to solely use redbean.

like:

```
public function beforeControllerAction(){
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));   
// other code to execute...
parent::beforeControllerAction(); 
}

    public function afterControllerAction(){
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));

// other code to execute...
parent::afterControllerAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use Readbean ORM with out any option, you can use redbean queries type like

```
$result = R::$f->begin()->select('*')->from('users')->where(' username = ? ')->put($_xusername)->get('row');
```

here u dont need to register or unregister autoloads